# SOLR no luck with long query, try shorter one

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have this problem, right now when I do a search like:

```
"really long search for something"
```

Solr returns no results, that is good actually, that is how I want it. But what I would like to do now is offer the user alternatives like:

```
"really long search for something" - sorry no luck

"really long search" - found 2 results

"really long" - found 10 results

"really" - found 25 results
```

I just dont know if there is some simple way of doing this in SOLR or I have to manually cut the search phrase and do new search with every phrase above?

Thanks for advice, even no way this is not possible would be very helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would surely end up performing multiple calls for each queries either through client or implementing a Custom Request Handler.

A [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093) raised already to address the issue, you can check on it .

Something on the same lines might also help - 
http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html